# NullReferenceException in formsdata.dll

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have the following code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("PName");
            dt.Columns.Add("Rate");
            dt.Columns.Add("Qty");
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            ViewState["v1"] = dt;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)ViewState["vi"];
        string sPname = TextBox1.Text;
        string sRate = TextBox2.Text;
        string sQty = TextBox3.Text;
        double d1 = Convert.ToDouble(sRate)* Convert.ToDouble(sQty);

        DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
        dr[0] = sPname;
        dr[1] = sRate;
        dr[2] = sQty;
        dr[3] = d1.ToString("0.00");
        dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt2.AcceptChanges();
        ViewState["v1"] = dt2;

        GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Error Here:**

```
DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Formsdata.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

After inserting values and clicking on button.
I'm using visual studio 2013, beginner!

Comment: Whenever you ask about an exception, you must post the full exception, including the stack trace and inner exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ViewState` object from which you are getting the `DataTable` doesn't contain any `DataTable`.

The issue is that you are assigning the `DataTable` in a `ViewState` object which has the key **v1** but you are accessing it from **vi**. So **vi** doesn't contain anything.

Try with this in the first line of your button click event handler code.

```
DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)ViewState["v1"];
```

Comment: No, they both say 'v1'.

Comment: @JohnSaunders look at the very first line of button click handler. `DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)ViewState["vi"];`.

Comment: My bad. I didn't see that one. I can't change my vote unless you make some edit. Let me know when you do, and I'll upvote.

Comment: +1. This is the answer. And it's still a duplicate of What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?